# MODE command and registry/device manager show different values for COMx port Baud.Which one is correct?

Tags: windows, serial-port

Ports registry settings :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Ports
```

have this value about my COM3 port - `9600,n,8,1` (same in the device manager)

the `MODE` command about the same port prints:

```
baud:1200
Parity:Even
Data Bits:7
Stop Bits:1
```

Which value is correct and why they differs?

Comment: In the olden days, serial port drivers would emulate an UART chip at the register level.  Ensuring that they still work when used from a DOS program.  Those days are over.  Never ever depend on default initialization, you must use SetCommState() to get a predictable outcome.

Comment: @HansPassant - you can put this as answer .Thanks to the clue you give I 've found this tool - https://batchloaf.wordpress.com/serialsend/ which fits perfectly my needs.